Trying to execute order at noon
I'm trying to execute an order after 12:31pm based on the noon price.  I'd like to draw a line at noon and if price crosses the line enter a position.  I can't seem to figure out how to reference the noon price or the line in the commands.
strategy("Noon Line Strategy", overlay=true)

_h = 12  // Hour: 12
_m = 00  // Minute: 0
inWindow = (hour(time) == _h) and (minute(time) == _m)

var line lineNoon = na

if (inWindow)
    lineNoon := line.new(bar_index, high, bar_index + 1, high, extend = extend.right)

//Set trade condition values
tradeEntry = ta.crossover(close, lineNoon)
tradeExit = ta.crossunder(close, lineNoon)

allowedTimes() => time(timeframe = timeframe.period, session = "1231-1500", timezone = "America/New_York")

if tradeEntry and allowedTimes()
    strategy.entry("Enter Long", strategy.long, profit=40)
    
if tradeExit
    strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry = "Enter Long")```


FYI in this code the lineNoon reference in the crossover / crossunder does not work.

Why do you need the line? It is only a visual aid. You need the price level at noon and trigger some visual aid WHEN current price crosses that.

Ofcourse it won't work, lineNoon is a Line object, I wonder why it hasn't thrown any errors... For the crossover/crossunder you have to use an explicit price value. Save the value at noon (into a var variable) and use that variable in the crossover/under. I need to check why Pine allows to crossunder with a Line object, probably it grabs a Float value from the object.
